# Переменные в веб-приложении

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Как разобраться, где какие переменные моего приложения находятся( память клиента или сервера) и кто к ним имет доступ(один клиент к одной переменной или каждый клиент к каждой например). Т.е. если в классе контроллера я создаю

```
  private string s="s";
```

то кто и в каких случаях может видеть эту переменную и изменять ее значение, а также как он делит эту возможность с другими. также интересует как обстоит дело с другими переменными - например статическими публичными полями класса, закрытыми, локальными переменными циклов и тд. Где все это можно почитать или подглядеть ?

Comment: В любой книге по асп-нет мвц

Comment: Подскажите, какие книги и на каких страницах. Я прочел уже три и не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная доступна только на сервере, **`private`** переменная видна только внутри метода, где она объявлена, если она объявлена в методе, или внутри класса где она объявлена, если она объявлена в классе. Но если в классе, то ее могут менять и видеть другие методы в контроллере (в принципе `class=controller`)

**UPD. Если ты не передаешь переменную во `view`**

Comment: @Sleepless, используйте, пожалуйста, кириллицу.